# Is there a way to generate(emit) code at runtime in medium trust?

Tags: .net, asp.net, reflection, .net-3.5, medium-trust

I would like to know if there is something similar to CSharpCodeProvider, but it should work in ASP.NET Medium Trust, anyone knows a good one?

---

**[EDIT 08-25-2009]**

**Why I want to do that?**

I was writing a simple tutorial about Link to Objects and I would like users could write some simple querys on a textbox, post it to server to see the results, something like "linqpad" does today. Is there a way to do that? or not... I will  have to live with that?

Comment: (noob at .Net says:) Isn't VBCodeProvider compatible with ASP.Net?

Comment: yes, it is. but it works like CSharpCodeProvider (only in full trust)